# Videos from document library on Sharepoint Page starts automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, video

We've got a problem with videos on our SharePoint pages.
The thing is the clips were fine month ago. Now they are starting automatically.
[image: Sharepoint article video]
Any solution ideas? Plain old SharePoint videos from the document library. No configuration options. 
Tested on newest Chrome, Edge and Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using File Viewer web part to view the video. Per my testing, it will autoplay the video.

If you don't want it to play automatically, you can use [Embed web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8) or [Stream web part](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-the-stream-web-part-b97fa87c-1337-4271-a059-17f0d2b26e8b).

method 1: Use Embed web part and display video using `iframe` and with to `autoplay=false` attribute.

method 2: Upload the video to Stream https://web.microsoftstream.com/. On the modern page, display the video via Stream web part.

Comment: Thanks! The microsoft streams are working fine!

Comment: Good advice ... if my company permitted me to use the Embed web part, or had set up Stream. Since neither is true, apparently I can't stop autoplay at all. Annoying.